# Additional SubQuestions in the comments

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292520/webrtc-how-many-stun-turn-servers-do-i-need-to-specify), I'm pretty sure it was true answer as the user asked.

However when I asked him why he didn't accept it, he mentioned additional details in the comments like: `"What I wanted to know it was useful or not?"` and other **subQuestions**.

When someone adds **SubQuestions** in a comment, Do I have to edit my answer until he finishes  adding all **subQuestions** in his mind?

In general, shouldn't he ask another Question instead of adding it in the comments?

Comment: related chameleon questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Also be aware for [help vampires](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Answer (score 2):

No. You shouldn't edit your answer for OP's sub questions. (*You can if you wish though*)

> In general, shouldn't he ask another Question instead of adding it in the comments?

No. It **has** to be asked as a separate question.

So, kindly comment `"Please ask a separate questions"` and if OP still bothers you, you don't bother about him.